In a normed vector space X. B(0,r) is homeomorph to space X .
Let $X$ a normed space.
I tried to prove that in a normed vector space X. B(0,r) is  homeomorph to space X }by using this function:
$f: X \to B(0,r) $
$f(x)= \frac{rx}{1+\|x\|}$
I can prove that is a surjective function. but I want to prove that is a injective and continuous.
I tried like this:
for injection :
let $x_1,x_2 \in X : f(x_1)=f(x_2) \Rightarrow \frac{rx_1}{1+\|x_1\|}=\frac{rx_2}{1+\|x_2\|} \Rightarrow \frac{x_1}{1+\|x_1\|} =\frac{x_2}{1+\|x_2\|} $
But I don't know how I can continue!
for continuity:
$ Let x_0 \in X. Let \epsilon > 0 $
$\| f(x)-f(x_0)\| = \| \frac{rx}{1+\| x \|}-\frac{rx_0}{1+\|x_0\|} \| = \frac{r}{(1+\|x\|)(1+\|x_0\|)}.(x+x\|x_0\|-x_0-x_0\|x\|)$
but I don't got any thing from that!
Any help?

$\frac 1 {1+|x|}$ is continuous because $|x|$ is continuous. $rx$ is continuous, so the product is continuous. [Use sequential continuity instead of $\epsilon -\delta$ definition.

For injectivity take norm on both sides of $\frac{x_1}{1+|x_1|} =\frac{x_2}{1+|x_2|}$. BTW, ths question has been answered long ago.

@geetha290krm I tried that and I got that $|x_1|=|x_2|$ but this does not mean that $x_1=x_2$ for example; $ |-1|=|1| $ but $1 \neq -1$

@geetha290krm for continuity we know that sequential continuity is eual to $\epsilon \delta $ continuity. But is this true in any normed vector space?

@geetha290krm Also I have another question; you said that $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ is continuous but this function in R not in X. for example; if we take X as a vector space of bounded sequences then this function's range is in R not in X. so if we using that the product is continuous , this isn't a problem? because we take two functions that thier range is diffrenet then thier norm in thier range is different

There is no problem. If $a_n \to a$ in the scalar field and $x_n \to x$ oin $X$ them $a_n x_n \to ax$ in $X$.

@geetha290krm ok, thanks. what about the injectivity? I got that $|x_1|=|x_2| $ but I have to prove that $x_1=x_2$

Go back to $\frac{x_1}{1+|x_1|} =\frac{x_2}{1+|x_2|} $

I got it. thank you very much
